# MS Access - asset/equipment tracking and temperature monitoring system

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, database-relations

I am fairly new to MS Access but have been asked to design a database to keep track of our equipment at my company. Fairly straightforward but some of our equipment is temperature controlled and connected to a piece of software called an Equipment/Environmental Monitoring System that records temperature and CO2 readings. Therefore there needs to be three columns on my database that includes: the brand name of the EMS the equipment is on (currently there are four, but soon to be two, in use in the building), the logger/probe ID the temperature is recorded on, and again for the CO2 logger/probe (only applicable to incubators).

My issue is that most of our equipment (~700 unique pieces of equipment) actually isn't on the EMS (e.g. thermometers, pipettes, balances, printers) therefore I would be left with a column on my table that is mainly blank (and even more so for CO2 Logger name, as only incubators have CO2 readings). Therefore, approximately 400 pieces of equipment are on an EMS (total ~1100 pieces of equipment).

I was hoping someone could help about how best to design the database. Should the EMS and logger IDs be on a separate table? I initially thought so but I am having trouble with the relationship type if so. Not all equipment is on the EMS. Then I thought a 1:1 relationship?
I am just concerned that there would be significant amount of nulls if the EMS and logger IDs were on the same table.
Thanks,

Comment: Could you think how to split your question into more smaller ones? Perhaps it would make it easier to answer.

Comment: Blank fields is not strict normalization but not totally forbidden either. It is a balancing act between normalization and ease of data entry/output. Normalize until it hurts and denormalize until it works.

Comment: It is fine to have fields that are only used by some of your records, especially for such small number of records (1100). There is no real reason to create a second table and a relationship.